# How to set skin on XtraUserControl in Windows Form?

Tags: c#, devexpress-windows-ui

I have a simple Windows Form. In it, I've embedded a ChildXtraUserControl which derives from XtraUserControl (DevEx v10.1).

I'd like to skin the ChildXtraUserControl with 'Office 2010 Blue', and I'm expecting it to look bluish when I run the form. I've tried this two different ways but am unable to get it to work.

**Attempt 1: Set the LookAndFeel in the ChildXtraUserControl, set the ChildXtraUserControl into a Windows Form Panel in the form**

When I run this, I see only the Panel, which I've colored pale yellow.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var devExUserControl = new DevExpressUserControl {Dock = DockStyle.Fill};
        panel1.Controls.Add(devExUserControl);
    }
}

public partial class ChildXtraUserControl : XtraUserControl
{
    public ChildXtraUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        IntializeSkin();
    }

    private void IntializeSkin()
    {
        LookAndFeel.UseDefaultLookAndFeel = false;
        LookAndFeel.UseWindowsXPTheme = false;
        LookAndFeel.Style = LookAndFeelStyle.Skin;
        LookAndFeel.SkinName = "Office 2010 Blue";
    }
}
```

**Attempt 2: I read [on the DevEx Support Center](https://www.devexpress.com/support/center/question/details/q495968) that the ChildXtraUserControl could be in a DevExpress PanelControl, and the LookAndFeel set on the PanelControl**

As before, I only see the pale yellow PanelControl. The post does seem like it was for a different DevEx version, but I thought it was worth a shot.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        panelControl1.LookAndFeel.UseDefaultLookAndFeel = false;
        panelControl1.LookAndFeel.UseWindowsXPTheme = false;
        panelControl1.LookAndFeel.Style = LookAndFeelStyle.Skin;
        panelControl1.LookAndFeel.SkinName = "Office 2010 Blue";

        var devExUserControl = new ChildXtraUserControl { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
        panelControl1.Controls.Add(devExUserControl);
    }
}

public partial class ChildXtraUserControl : XtraUserControl
{
    public ChildXtraUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this to work by using the second approach and modifying the Form1 constructor as shown.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // add this line
        DevExpress.UserSkins.OfficeSkins.Register();

        panelControl1.LookAndFeel.UseDefaultLookAndFeel = false;
        panelControl1.LookAndFeel.UseWindowsXPTheme = false;
        panelControl1.LookAndFeel.Style = LookAndFeelStyle.Skin;
        panelControl1.LookAndFeel.SkinName = "Office 2010 Blue";

        var childXtraUserControl = new ChildXtraUserControl {Dock = DockStyle.Fill};
        panelControl1.Controls.Add(childXtraUserControl);
    }
```

Comment: Also, to get children DevEx controls (e.g. ComboBoxEdit) of the ChildXtraUserControl to be skinned the same way, I had to embed a StyleController in the ChildXtraUserControl (using the designer), set up the LookAndFeel on it, and set the StyleController property of each child control.